# Fastest way to calculate euclidian distance in 2D space

Tags: python, optimization, distance

What is the fastes way of determening which point q out of n points in 2D space is the closest (smallest euclidian distance) to point p, see attached imgage.

[image]

My current method of doing this in Python is storing all the distances in a list and then running

```
numpy.argmin(list_of_distances)
```

This is however a bit slow when calculating this for m number of points p. Or is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This falls under [closest point query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_point_query) -problems.

How many points are expected? Are your points static or do they change? One naive but powerful approach for static points would be to pre-compute every known distance, which would result in O(1) lookup.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. n is normaly only around 10 but m can range in the thousands. However, the distrubution of q i liklely to change with every iteration. "Precompute every known distance", does this apply to floating point numbers?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of calculating the distances, you could calculate the squared distances. That way you don't need to perform n * m square roots.

Comment: Old games programmer's cheat :)

Answer (score 1):

Put everything as soon as possible into numpy and do calculations there. If you have many points, it is much faster than calculating distances in lists:

```
import numpy as np

px, py
x = np.fromiter(point.x for point in points, dtype = np.float)
y = np.fromiter(point.y for point in points, dtype = np.float)

i_closest = np.argmin((x - px) ** 2 + (y - py) ** 2)
```